# How to convert JavaScript snippet extracted from YouTube to comply with JSON

Tags: javascript, python, json, youtube

Is there a way to process the following string to make it comply with JSON standard? (keys and values should be in double quotes)

```
{ 'VIDEO_ID': "3xOYjRcgibA", 'LIST_ID': "PLfKGJrRXSczdRU1RCcEOJ9TDtvWUA1VU2", 'WAIT_TO_DELAYLOAD_FRAME_CSS': true, 'IS_UNAVAILABLE_PAGE': false, 'DROPDOWN_ARROW_URL': "\/yts\/img\/pixel-vfl3z5WfW.gif", 'AUTONAV_EXTRA_CHECK': false, 'JS_PAGE_MODULES': [ 'www/watch', 'www/ypc_bootstrap', 'www/watch_speedyg', 'www/watch_autoplayrenderer', '' ], "text": [ 'It shouldn\'t replace here', 'And don't here' ], 'test': 5 }
```

The snippet was extracted from *YouTube* web page *JavaScript* code.

Following *python* code is an attempt to extract the string from webpage, and convert it into data structure

```
import codecs
import requests
import json
import re

url  = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xOYjRcgibA&list=PLfKGJrRXSczdRU1RCcEOJ9TDtvWUA1VU2'

page = requests.get(url)
html = page.content
html = html.decode('utf-8')
html = html.replace('\n','')
html = re.sub(' +',' ',html)

p = re.compile('yt.setConfig\((.*?)\);')
str = p.findall(html)
s = str[0]
data = json.loads(s)
```

Output

```
C:\temp\work\python>temp.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\temp\work\python\temp.py", line 17, in <module>
    data = json.loads(s)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)
```

In perl desired result can be achieved with following code

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $data = <DATA>;

$data =~ s/'(.*?)'([:, \]])/"$1"$2/gs;

say $data;

__DATA__
{ 'VIDEO_ID': "3xOYjRcgibA", 'LIST_ID': "PLfKGJrRXSczdRU1RCcEOJ9TDtvWUA1VU2", 'WAIT_TO_DELAYLOAD_FRAME_CSS': true, 'IS_UNAVAILABLE_PAGE': false, 'DROPDOWN_ARROW_URL': "\/yts\/img\/pixel-vfl3z5WfW.gif", 'AUTONAV_EXTRA_CHECK': false, 'JS_PAGE_MODULES': [ 'www/watch', 'www/ypc_bootstrap', 'www/watch_speedyg', 'www/watch_autoplayrenderer', '' ], "text": [ 'It shouldn\'t replace here', 'And don't here' ], 'test': 5 }
```

Output

```
{ "VIDEO_ID": "3xOYjRcgibA", "LIST_ID": "PLfKGJrRXSczdRU1RCcEOJ9TDtvWUA1VU2", "WAIT_TO_DELAYLOAD_FRAME_CSS": true, "IS_UNAVAILABLE_PAGE": false, "DROPDOWN_ARROW_URL": "\/yts\/img\/pixel-vfl3z5WfW.gif", "AUTONAV_EXTRA_CHECK": false, "JS_PAGE_MODULES": [ "www/watch", "www/ypc_bootstrap", "www/watch_speedyg", "www/watch_autoplayrenderer", "" ], "text": [ "It shouldn\'t replace here", "And don't here" ], "test": 5 }
```

Comment: You could try `ast.literal_eval()`.

Comment: @Barmar -- it produced an error `ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x03E18D90>`

Comment: I guess it doesn't work because Python uses `False` but JS uses `false`.

Comment: Unfortunately, what you need is a JavaScript parser. Anything ad hoc like this will not be robust if the coding style changes.

Comment: https://github.com/darkf/py-js-object-parser

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
import codecs
import requests
import json
import re

url  = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xOYjRcgibA&list=PLfKGJrRXSczdRU1RCcEOJ9TDtvWUA1VU2'

page = requests.get(url)
html = page.content
html = html.decode('utf-8')
html = html.replace('\n','')
html = re.sub(' +',' ',html)

p = re.compile('yt.setConfig\((.*?)\);')
str = p.findall(html)
s = str[0]
with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(s, outfile)
with open('data.txt') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
print(data)
```

Comment: It produces a string but not data structure (dict). An attempt to redirect output into a file for debug purpose produces empty file.

Comment: Dumped the string into a json file 'data.txt', loaded the json file back to variable 'data'.